# mysql select column outside group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, min

I have the following dataset

```
ID  P   C1    C2    XR  
1   1   GBP   USD   1.6
2   2   GBP   USD   1.7
3   1   GBP   EUR   0.84
4   2   GBP   EUR   0.83
5   1   GBP   CHF   1.8
6   2   GBP   CHF   1.8
```

I'm trying to get the minimum XR for each pair so the results should be

```
ID  P   C1    C2    XR  
1   1   GBP   USD   1.6
4   2   GBP   EUR   0.83
5   1   GBP   CHF   1.8
```

but when I `SELECT MIN(XR) GROUP BY C1,C2`, I either dont get the correct ID or get a warning saying ID not in GROUP BY if 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY' enabled

Closest I've got is this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.C1, t1.C2, MIN(t2.XR) FROM xrates t1 
LEFT JOIN xrates AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.C1, t1.C2
HAVING t1.C1 = 'GBP' AND t1.C2 IN ('USD','EUR')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select rates.*
from xrates rates
where id in 
(
    select min(xrates.id) as minid    
    from xrates
    inner join
    (
        select C1, C2, MIN(XR) as minxr
        from xrates
        GROUP BY C1, C2
        HAVING C1 = 'GBP'
    ) x on x.c1 = xrates.c1 and x.c2 = xrates.c2 and x.minxr = xrates.xr
    group by xrates.C1, xrates.C2
)
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48120/17)

Comment: I found a problem when x and y have the same xr, then it returns both results

Comment: Then you need some way of breaking the deadlock. Which row is the 'right' one?

Comment: the important thing is returning each unique pair with the lowest xr

Comment: i can add `GROUP BY C1,C2` to the end so long as sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` isnt enabled but it isnt a fool proof server setup solution

Comment: I made an edit to it but not sure if it auto saves it.  Your decimal also needed to be 5,2  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48120/7/0

Comment: seems like having to perform an extra operation but ill mark your answer as correct anyway because you got me to a point that works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN 
    (SELECT grouping _id,MIN(ordering_id) min_ordering_id FROM my_table GROUP BY grouping_id) y
  ON y.grouping_id = x.grouping_id 
   AND y.min_ordering_id = x.ordering_id;
```

(note that the 'grouping_id' may be formed on more than one column!)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to join the table to itself, and you do not want to GROUP BY the id or every row is going to be unique. The following should return the results you specify:

```
SELECT 
    xrates.id, 
    xrates.C1, 
    xrates.C2, 
    MIN(xrates.XR) 
FROM xrates 
WHERE xrates.C1 = 'GBP' 
AND xrates.C2 IN ('USD','EUR')
GROUP BY 
    xrates.C1, 
    xrates.C2;
```

Comment: I have obviously missed something; I thought he was looking for the lowest XR for each C1 / C2 pair?

Comment: The op wants the *corresponding* id too.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies.